# Mouse hovering didn't work if the href is set to a block

Tags: jquery, html

So i have 3 pics that need to be linked to other page, and it fadeIn with hovering.
But i noticed that the jquery affect will be disabled once the image arrange in a block in CSS.
And solution?

The CSS:

```
div {
display: none;
width: 600px;
margin: auto;
}

.row_1 img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.row_2 img{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.row_1,
.row_2{
    display: inline-block;
}

.row_2 img{
    display: block;
}
.row_1 img{
    display: block;
}
```

The Html code:

```
<div>



<h2>Blog</h2>




<div class ="row">

<span class ="row_1">
<a href="#"><img src="image/under.png" /></a>
</span>

<span class ="row_2">
<a href='#'><img src="image/under.png" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="image/under.png" /></a>
</span>

</div>


</div>
```

The jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a').fadeTo(1,0.5);


  $('a').hover(
      function () {
       $(this).fadeTo('slow',1);
      }, 
      function () {
         $(this).fadeTo('slow',0.5);
      }
    );      

});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: setting to $('a img').hover won't help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to both change the order of fading in your hover, and target the image and not the anchor element. Make this change:

```
$('a').hover(
    function() {
        $('img',this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
    }, 
    function() {
        $('img',this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k5uUV/)**.

Comment: You've got a double-fade going on there.  The link is faded to 50% on document load, and the you are fading the images by 50% on hover, so you end up with something like 25% on mouseover.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: this work, but the another problem is that i want my pic to be 50% faded when the document is ready.

     $(".img_link").fadeTo(1,0.5);
if all my img have class="img_link"
It doesn't work...can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `display` to `block` shouldn't make a difference.

I pasted your code here and it seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/cG8c9/

Your problem probably lies elsewhere.  Can you reproduce it at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Also, I don't know if you are generalizing for your example, but I would avoid doing any jQuery on just selector `div`.  Give your main wrapper an ID and use that.  Also, add `.stop()` before your fade effects, otherwise you will get cycling behavior if you mousein/out too quickly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').fadeTo(1, 0.5);
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn('slow');

    $('a').hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/cG8c9/1/

**Edit:** I tested in IE and see that the fade doesn't work on the link at all.  You need to do your fades on the images in this case:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').fadeTo(1, 0.5);
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn('slow');

    $('a').hover(function() {
        $('img', this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }, function() {
        $('img', this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.5);
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cG8c9/2/

Comment: Really?
I dont see any fade effect on ur link

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?  Wait.  On my example?  When I hover over the image, it fades in, and when I mouseout, it fades to 50%.  Isn't that what you are expecting?

Comment: Also, which browser are you using?